# Xcode 10 image button states on OSX

Tags: xcode, macos

I recently got back into Xcode, and wanted to know how to apply images to various image button or button states in Xcode 10 on OSX Mojave, such as highlighted and normal? Seems like I can only set the normal state.

Comment: This is NSButton or UIButton?

Comment: NSButton on OSX, for an OSX app.

Comment: There is no such thing as highlighted vs normal state. Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326337/lost-in-nsbutton-types-and-alternate-images

Comment: Not for a toggle button though. I wanted it to show a different image when pressed down on a normal push button.

Comment: I think the linked answer tells you very clearly what you have to work with.

Comment: Already tried it, wasn't what I was talking about.

Comment: Let me specify a little further, take a look at the IOS camera app, when you take a photo it contracts a small circle a bit, if you hold it down it does a burst shot, once you release the button goes back to its normal white circle. On the record button it does an animation between states as well, the record button is a good use of states, but what about the screenshot button that has multiple functionalities? I'm only concerned for right now though about a change during whatever "pressed in" event occurs, such as a finger down on the trackpad.

Comment: On UIButton for IOS there's an isSelected property, touchDownInside and touchUpInside events, I'm just wondering if there's an equivalent for NSButton on Cocoa for OSX, or a way to make it behave like UIButton a bit more.

Comment: I know what there is on UIButton. That's why I asked if you were perhaps confusing it with NSButton. NSButton is not UIButton and it doesn't work at all like it. The linked answer tells you the sort of thing you have available to you with NSButton.

Comment: By the way, don't forget to examine NSButtonCell; a lot of NSButton's functionality lies there.